# Fetch X-GM-THRID X-GM-MSGID for all unseen messages using python

Tags: python-3.x, automation, gmail-api, gmail-imap, imaplib

when i try to fetch X-GM-THRID and X-GM-MSGID for each mail using uid via for loop it fetch only 1st unseen mail X-GM-THRID and X-GM-MSGID rest are none. why and how to fetch the X-GM-THRID and X-GM-MSGID of all unseen mail one by one.

---

```
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.
result, data = mail.search(None, "UNSEEN")
ids = data[0] # data is a list.
id_list = ids.split() # ids is a space separated string
print(id_list)
for uid in id_list:
result, data = mail.uid('fetch',uid, '(X-GM-MSGID)')
print(data)
pattern= re.compile(r'\d{19}')
pattern=pattern.search (str(data[0]))
MSG_ID=('X-GM-MSGID: %s'%pattern)
print(MSG_ID)

result, data = mail.uid('fetch',uid,'(X-GM-THRID)')
pattern= re.compile(r'\d{19}')
pattern=pattern.search(str(data[0]))
THR_ID=('X-GM-THRID: %s'%pattern)
print(THR_ID)
output:
[b'23 (X-GM-MSGID 1661402455636098002 UID 85)']
X-GM-MSGID: <re.Match object; span=(17, 36), match='1661402455636098002'>
X-GM-THRID: <re.Match object; span=(17, 36), match='1661402455636098002'>
[None]
X-GM-MSGID: None
X-GM-THRID: None
[None]
X-GM-MSGID: None
X-GM-THRID: None
[None]
X-GM-MSGID: None
X-GM-THRID: None
[None]
X-GM-MSGID: None
X-GM-THRID: None
```

rather than none i need msgid and thrid of each mail sepreately. 
how to achieve this.

Comment: You are mixing message sequence numbers and UID s.  Use both `search` and `fetch`; or `uid search` and `uid fetch`.   You are using sequence `search`, but `uid fetch`.

Comment: could u please elaborate.

Comment: That's it.  If you want to use `UID FETCH`, you must use `UID SEARCH`  (mail.uid('search', ...) and mail.uid('fetch'...).  If you want to use `SEARCH`, you must use plain `FETCH`.  mail.search(..) and mail.fetch(...).   You can not mix them, they return different message identifiers.